# Is it possible to know what file is downloaded by Firefox with Selenium

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, download, firefox-addon

first of all, I'm sorry for my English

I am doing some scripting in Python using Selenium RC.
The aim is to access to some website, and download some files
I would like to know, at the end of the script, what files exactly have been downloaded

At that moment, I'm doing something a bit naive, which is checking the new files who appears in the download directory of Firefox, it's working well but if I launch severals clients in the same times, they can't detect which files they own etc...

So i was trying to find a solution to that problem, if it's possible to handle the download from Firefox to know exactly when a download occur, and what is downloaded, then I would be super fine, but so far, I haven't find anything about that

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with python-->Selenium RC why don't you just
create a lastdownload.txt type of file, and put in the dates, filenames
of the files you download.

So each time your script runs, it will check the fileserver, and your log file
to see which files are new, which files you already have. (if same filename is used
you can check the lastupdatetime of headers, or even the filesize as a way to compare)

Then you just download the new files... so this way you replicate a simple incremental mechanism with lookup on a txt file...

Comment: The problem with that solution is that if there is multiple clients connecting to the same server and downloading in the same time some files with Selenium RC, it's not possible to know which client downloaded what file.




For example, if client1 download file1 and client2 download file2 at the same time, that solution will imply that client1 and client2 downloaded both files

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find something to answer my problem (Firefox only), the code is enough clear to understand (you should refer to state and target from moz_downloads in the Firefox API)

```
def check_download(self):
    isDownloading = False
    t = 0
    while t != 60 or isDownloading:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(self.finalFolder, "downloads.sqlite"), os.path.join(self.log_dir, self.sessionId+"downloads.sqlite"))
        conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(self.log_dir, self.sessionId+"downloads.sqlite"))
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("select state, target from moz_downloads")
        print '<waiting for download>'
        for row in c:
            dlState = row[0]
            dlTarget = row[1]
            if dlState == 0 or dlState == 7 or dlState == -1:
                isDownloading = True
            if self.verbose:
                print "status: {0} | target: {1}".format(dlState, dlTarget)
            if dlState == 1:
                filenameExpected = os.path.join(self.download_dir, os.path.split(dlTarget)[1])
                self.writeline_log("FILE;" + filenameExpected + ';')
                return
        c.close()
        conn.close()
        time.sleep(1)
        t = t + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but I would consider setting up multiple Firefox profiles each set with a different download directory and then telling my instances to use those profiles (or maybe programmatically setting profile values if you're using Selenium2 - I'm not sure if download directory is possible to change or not). Then you can keep monitoring each directory and seeing what was downloaded for each session.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Just create a new folder everytime and download your file there.
Make sure the foldername is incremented if it already exits (Ex: folder1, folder2, Folder3.....)